# Line renderer between two points(no world space)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to achieve drawing a line between two points. They work well when I use the toggle function of using the world space but unfortunately do not work if I use world space as false. The reason I want the world space to remain false is because the line is parented to a gameObject and I move this parent gameObject. So is there a solution where I can draw line between two points?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SetPosition_Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer line;
    public GameObject TargetPoint;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        line.SetPosition(1, TargetPoint.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: ```transform.position``` is in world space.  If you want to work in local (object/non-world) space, you need to use ```transform.localPosition```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to set the positions continuously in the update. These are set as an array of vector3 to the component.
I would suggest to check that out first in the editor, as the component itself has the tool to add the points manually with raycasts in the scene (which is very useful to understand how the component works), and then try that out with code.
You would need to take a look in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html#LineSettings) and to try to set the line points with code, you can have this pseudocode as an starting point:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SetPosition_Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer line;
    public GameObject TargetPoint;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        // line.useWorldSpace = false;
        // line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        Vector3[] pathPoints = { new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(10,10,10) };
        line .positionCount = 2;
        line .SetPositions(pathPoints);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // in the start enough. not need to do it un the update to just draw the line
    }
}
```

Note that this is pseudo code, and that I take your exmaple as an starting point. I am not clear about the role of `useWorldSpace` in your problem so I comment that out and I think that the way the points are set is the main problem.
If you need the line to move or set it in the update, you would need to clear its `Vector3[]` array of points and set it every time, this is, repeat the step I am trying to suggest you in the `Start()` in the `Update()`